# Why the correlation in CCA can be greater than 1?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, correlation, canonical-correlation

I am working with the following paper [https://home.ttic.edu/~klivescu/papers/andrew_icml2013.pdf](https://home.ttic.edu/%7Eklivescu/papers/andrew_icml2013.pdf) where they use DCCA and in the results they present they show correlations between different sets of variables greater than 1. How is this possible? What is the difference between the correlation they are showing and a regular correlation coefficient?

Comment: Just before eq (10) that paper states "the total correlation
of the top k components of H1 and H2 is the sum of the
top k singular values of the matrix T..."  Is this *total correlation* what you are referring to?